# How do I train a dataset using LinearSVM?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I am currently new in Machine learning and wanted to ask how to train a dataset. My dataset is a folder that consist of images of alphabets. This is the code that I am working on and currently stuck on the trainset.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import os
import cv2
import joblib

Dataset_folder = 'Dataset/'

directory = os.listdir(Dataset_folder)
folders = directory

folders =  sorted(folders)

print (folders)

trainset = []

for folder in directory:
    flist = os.listdir(os.path.join(Dataset_folder, folder))
    for f in flist:
        img = cv2.imread(Dataset_folder + folder + "/" + f,0)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (36,36))
        trainset.append(img)
print ('done')
# Labeling for trainset
train_label = []
for i in range(0,10):
    temp = 140*[i]
    train_label += temp

trainset = np.reshape(trainset, (4650, -1))

# Create an linear SVM object
clf = LinearSVC()

# Perform the training
clf.fit(trainset, train_label)
print("Training finished successfully")
```

Comment: please add the error message.

Comment: Why do you reshape it to a 1D feature vector with size 4650? The image has been resized to 36x36 and if it has 3 channels then 36x36x3 = 3888. Am I missing something?

Comment: It works now, I just change some details but I just wanted to know if I should create 2 datasets: 1 for training and 1 for testing.